# How to remove info button on iOS MapBox?

Tags: ios, mapbox

I just integrated MapBox into my iOS project and noticed that info button in bottom right. How to remove it? It will confuse a lot of people later on.

[image]

Comment: A bit late but have you tried `mapView.attributionButton.hidden = true`?

Answer (score 25):

Set

```
mapView.logoView.isHidden = true
mapView.attributionButton.isHidden = true
```

and in info.plist

`MGLMapboxMetricsEnabledSettingShownInApp` to `YES`

Comment: As the name of that Info.plist key suggests, only use this approach if you [provide your own setting](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/#telemetry_opt_out) for the user to opt out of Mapbox Telemetry (and provide equivalent copyright statements for Mapbox and OpenStreetMap).

Comment: This has been renamed to `mapView.ornaments.logoView.isHidden` and `mapView.ornaments.attributionButton.isHidden`

Answer (score 2):

You should keep that button like a sort of copyright:

> All uses of Mapbox’s custom maps and data must attribute both Mapbox
>   and the appropriate data providers. Mapbox’s custom design is
>   copyrighted and our data sources require attribution.
>
> ### Automatic attribution
>
> If you use a different Mapbox SDK library, like Mapbox.js or Mapbox
>   Mobile, the necessary attribution will be automatically included in
>   the bottom right corner of the map.

source: https://www.mapbox.com/help/attribution/

Comment: Mapbox states that this attribution can be elsewhere in the app

Answer (score 1):

### In MapBox iOS v10

Where `map` is an instance of `MapView`.

```swift
private func hideOrnaments() {
    map.ornaments.options.logo.margins = .init(x: -10000, y: 0)
    map.ornaments.options.attributionButton.margins = .init(x: -10000, y: 0)
    map.ornaments.options.scaleBar.visibility = .hidden
    map.ornaments.options.compass.visibility = .hidden
}
```

Keep in mind that you're supposed to show the logo and info button as requested by MapBox' terms and conditions.

It's obvious MapBox doesn't want you to hide their logo easily. But I've found a workaround by setting its margins to be off-screen.

Answer (score 1):

Just i added this and worked for me

```
  mapView.ornaments.attributionButton.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** remove the button for your app, then you would have to

- Modify the source and remove the [`_attributionButton`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/2354c87411ce88c581e02f93445a66a2158bd7b0/platform/ios/src/MGLMapView.mm#L434)
- recompile the iOS SDK and keep up with code changes from mapbox-gl-native (thereby losing any advantages of CocoaPods for Mapbox, if you use it).
- Then add in a custom User Interface for copyright and attribution.  (See link as @SaintThread mentions).

You still need to adhere to the [Mapbox terms of service](https://www.mapbox.com/tos/), so the above steps will be extra work with minimal gain.  Most maps users from any service are most likely used to an info button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add MGLMapboxMetricsEnabledSettingShownInApp into info.plist with YES value
2. Add the following code after mapView initialization:

   [mapView.logoView setHidden:YES];
   [mapView.attributionButton setHidden:YES];